# Unable to write in a file after django app deployment on aws ec2 using nginx and gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I have deployed my Django online judge project on AWS EC2 using Nginx and Gunicorn I am taking user code in a string variable and writing it to a file in my project directory and it's working fine in development server but after deployment the program unable to write code in the file. for eg:-

lets say a user have submitted code in c++ language so I took that code in a string variable and I open the my .cpp file via `open()` function in my `views.py` and writing the code in it.

```
filepath = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'language', 'forcpp.cpp')
cpp_code=open(filepath,"w")
cpp_code.write(user_problem_code)
cpp_code.close()
```

I have tried to modify path in every possible way but got unlucky in every try

I have my files in `language` folder in which I want to write user submitted code and my `views.py` are in `problempg` application

**my project directory structure:**

```
online_judge_project/
                    account/
                    homesrc/
                    language/ /* directory containing files in which I want to write */
                            forcpp.cpp   
                    media/
                    oj/ 
                      settings.py
                    problempg/  /* application containing views.py */
                             views.py
                    static/ 
                    staticfiles/ 
                    template/
                    manage.py
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for oj project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from importlib.resources import path
from pathlib import Path
import os
from .info import *

EMAIL_USE_TLS = EMAIL_USE_TLS
EMAIL_HOST = EMAIL_HOST
EMAIL_HOST_USER = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD
EMAIL_PORT = EMAIL_PORT
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATE_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'template')
FILES_DIR=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'language'))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost","<MY_IP_ADDRESS>"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'widget_tweaks',
    'account.apps.AccountConfig',
    'problempg.apps.ProblempgConfig',
    'homescr.apps.HomescrConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ckeditor',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'oj.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'oj.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "index"

STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages

MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.DEBUG: 'alert-info',
    messages.INFO: 'alert-info',
    messages.SUCCESS: 'alert-success',
    messages.WARNING: 'alert-warning',
    messages.ERROR: 'alert-danger',
}
```

may be the path I am using in development is different in EC2 server. I have develop this project on a windows machine and I am deploying it on Ubantu EC2 server or it's due to Nginx?

Comment: could you do a print of the filepath - maybe this helps already with debugging

Comment: I checked by printing the file path also I gave that path in open()  function but the problem still persist